# Trying to make a recursive batch file that will go through folders and convert from .tif to .pdf

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, recursion

I am trying to make a recursive batch file that will go through a set of folders and convert the file from `.tif` to `.pdf`.

The folders are all setup by year, month date:

> ```
> 2016   -January (1-31)
>        -February (1-28)
> ```

...down through the months and days. I am trying to write a batch file that will go through each of these folders and find any `.tif` files and convert them to `.pdf`. I am new to batch and scripting so I don't know exactly what I would need to write to make this happen. Here is what I got and most of it I found online.

I am using a program called Image Magick for the conversion:

```
@Echo on
cd C:\Users\ars001\Downloads\January\*)
%%v = .tif
for /r %%v in (C:\Users\ars001\Downloads\January\*) do convert "*.tif" "*.pdf"
```

Questions:

1. Can you make an extension a variable? For example `A= .pdf`?
2. Why does the variable use two Percent signs? Does that mean echo it?

The path in the question is an example folder and path I made on my local computer before trying it on the server.

example Path:

> ```
> January 1, 2
> ```

Comment: Where is the documentation for this magical convert command you are using?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Answer (score 0):

This line is what you're trying to do.

`FOR /R "C:\Users\ars001\Downloads" %%a in (*.tif) DO convert "%%~a" "%%~dpna.pdf"`

You can run this on the command line (instead of in a batch file) if you change `%%` to `%`. You need two `%%` in a batch file (because the cmd processor resolves all `%%variables` to `%variables` first, so if you didn't use two `%%`, the `FOR` syntax wouldn't work. But on the command line itself, you just need the one `%`.

Basically, it says to start in the Downloads folder, looking in all subfolders for any file that looks like *.tif. Then it converts each one it finds to PDF (assuming the ImageMagick convert.exe is in your path).

If you haven't picked it up, yes, you can specify parts of the filename. See the end of `HELP FOR`. In short, with `%A`, `%~dpnxA` means the drive, path, name, and extension of `%A`.

To delete the original after conversion, do this:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\ars001\Downloads" %%a in (*.tif) DO (
    convert "%%~a" "%%~dpna.pdf"
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" del "%%~a"
)
```

Another way to write the same thing (and on one line) is like this.

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\ars001\Downloads" %%a in (*.tif) DO convert "%%~a" "%%~dpna.pdf" && del "%%~a"
```

The `&&` says to only run the next bit if the command does not return an error (i.e. errorlevel 0).

Comment: Is there any way to get the function to delete the .tif file once it converts it to a .pdf ?

Comment: @Andrew11, yes.  Put a delete command after the convert command.

Comment: You probably only want to delete the original if the convert succeeds. I believe that ImageMagick's convert returns a non-zero error code should it fail during the process. So you'll want to include the check and the delete in the `FOR` block. I'll append it to the answer. If it answers, please consider accepting it.